# Print the key using the value of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, keras, key

I have a matrix `a=[0, 4, 8]` and what to find which keys in a dictionary `d = {"a":0, "b":1, "c":3, "d":4, "e":5, "f":6, "g":7, "h":8, "i":9, "j":10}` has the values in matrix a.

I have the following code:

```
for i in a:
    [key for key, value in d.items() if value == i]
    print(key)
```

However, when running this code I get the following message:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

I've tried adding .any() and .all() behind the array, but it doesn' work.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Show an example of `a` where we can recreate the error you are getting. Is `a` iterable?

Comment: You're not assigning anywhere that list comprehension. You probably want to append to a list. Also `key` is not defined anywhere, it only exists in the local *namespace*  within the list-comp, so it is not accessible from outside

Comment: The way you declared the dictionary is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably easiest:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if v in a:
        print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just reformat your code like this:

```
a = [0, 4, 8]
d = {"a":0, "b":1, "c":3, "d":4, "e":5, "f":6, "g":7, "h":8, "i":9, "j":10}

keys = [key for key in d.keys()if d[key] in a ]
print(keys)
# Output ['a', 'd', 'h']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the **key** of given **value** by **indexing method**.

> Code

```
a=[0, 4, 8]   #matrix a
d = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6, 'g':7, 'h':8, 'i':9, 'j':1}   #dictionary d

values = list(d.values())  #generating values list
keys = list(d.keys())    #generating keys list
for i in a:      #iterating over the elements of matrix or list a
    if i in values:    #chck whether the value in the dictionary
        print("Key for",i,"is",keys[values.index(i)])    #displaying result
```

> Output:

```
Key for 0 is a
Key for 4 is d
Key for 8 is h
```

I hope it would be helpful.